# How To Check if a new rectangle not collide with already drawn rectangles in canvas without loops

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I have a canvas in which i have to draw multiple rectagles with different width and height  with random x and y positions.Before drawing a new rectangle i have to check whether it collide with already drawn rectangles.Currently the solution that i am implimenting is to store the x,y positions and the width and height in array of objects of drawn rectangles and determine the collision through loop the array takes rectangles one by one and then check wheteher it is colliding with new rectangle.
It works but i want to check collision without looping through all existing rectangles.

Comment: If it's for perf reasons, then all other solutions would probably be slower - how many rectangles do you have and why do you need not to use loops?

Comment: ha-ha, well if you have a solid color background you can go all way around the new (potential) rectangle and check if you hit the color border. But this solution is dependant on too many things like color, fill etc.

Comment: @Nicholas Kyriakides  There are more than 100 rectangles and i dont want loop because of performance issues

Comment: You won't have any performance issue when looping within 100 rectangles. The time taken will be far below 0.1ms, and you have 16.6ms to do the job. The drawing is the most expensive part here.